# gradle-aws-plugin elasticbeanstalk how to deploy uploaded version

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a project in Android Studio with an Android Module and an Backend Module. The backend module produces a war file which I want to be deployed to AWS ElasticBeanstalk via the [gradle-aws-plugin](https://github.com/classmethod-aws/gradle-aws-plugin). The App creation and upload itself works fine. I can see the war file in the specified bucket and as version in my Beanstalk Application.

However I can't find a gradle task to deploy the new Version to my Environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk using the gradle-aws-plugin, however there is a [gradle-beanstalk-plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/fi.evident.beanstalk) which does exactly what you want with minimal configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [classmethod Gradle plugin](https://github.com/classmethod/gradle-aws-plugin) to upload files to S3, but I also cannot find any Gradle plugin to "deploy" to Elastic Beanstalk.

My current idea is to use the [eb deploy command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html) in a Gradle [exec task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html). I know this is sub-optimal, but it's the closest thing I can find.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with the `awsEbMigrateEnvironment` task provided by the plugin.

If you make it dependent in `build.gradle` like:

```
 ...
 awsEbCreateApplicationVersion.dependsOn uploadBundle
 awsEbMigrateEnvironment.dependsOn awsEbCreateApplicationVersion
```

and then do `gradle awsEbMigrateEnvironment`

Assuming you have configured everything correctly. 
A new bundle will be build, uploaded, new version created and also finally deployed to the environment you specified in the config:

```
beanstalk { 
    environment { 
        envName = ... 
        versionLabel = ...
    } 
 }
```

Or if you want to do it by hand you can remove the `dependsOn` and create a task like that:

```
import jp.classmethod.aws.gradle.elasticbeanstalk.*
task ebDeployGivenVersion(type: AWSElasticBeanstalkCreateEnvironmentTask){
     versionLabel = "${project.findProperty('wishedVersion') ?: 'foobar'}"   
}
```

and then:
`gradle ebDeployGivenVersion -PwishedVersion=v1.2`